# "The brakes went out on me."

Tags: phrase-usage

Someone  said:

> The brakes went out on me.

(to mean that the brakes had gone out).

Is the use of "went out on me" natural?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's natural.  "Go out" is a phrasal verb that means (among many other things) "to fail".  Example:

> I was raking leaves in the garden when suddenly my back **went out** (on me) and I dropped to the ground in pain.

Although it seems perfectly ordinary to me, I can't seem to find a dictionary that validates this use.  So perhaps it's a kind of informal variation on the use of "go out" as in "the fire *went out*".  In the same way the brakes "went out" as in "stopped doing what they were supposed to be doing".

Comment: So @Andrew , why is "on me" used?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish  "on me" is just an adverb phrase to explain who is the target of the action.  You could just as easily say *"the car had the brakes go out **on it** as it was going down a steep hill"*, but "on me" makes the consequences more personal.

Answer (score 1):

What is and is not idiomatic depends on several factors, so I’m not completely disagreeing with @Andrew. But with that in mind:

To my ears (native British English, specifically from Central Scotland) “the brakes went out on me” is not at all natural. I would always say simply that “the brakes failed on me”, or if the context was clear, just, “the brakes failed”.

Comment: Maybe it's an Americanism.  As someone born and bred in Southern California, "the brakes went out on me" would if anything be the preferred way to say it.

Comment: That’s perfectly plausible. Especially from California. You guys do appear to have a pronounced gift for synthesizing new English from old 

Comment: Dude, like thanks for the totally awesome response.

Answer (score 1):

There are two idioms being employed:

"Went out/go out" - to cease functioning, turn off, or fail in some way.
"On me" - to me, toward me, at me,  me.

A more literal way of expressing this sentiment is, depending on what they're trying to convey, "The brakes of my car failed," or, more dire, "The brakes of the car I was driving failed while I was driving it."